# Rearrange sub div after sort jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have several divs containing x content. I can sort them by data-* Thats working ok, but Some divs (not all) are followed by another div with class "detail". After the sort, these divs are "lost".

I can't figure out how to insert them after the sort (if existed)
Code:

```js
$('.sortableDiv').sort(sort_1).appendTo('#sortableContainer');

function sort_1(a, b) { 
    return ($(b).data('order')) < ($(a).data('order')) ? 1 : -1;  
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortableContainer">
<div class="sortableDiv" data-order="3">Div1</div>
    <div class="child1 detail">Child1</div>
<div class="sortableDiv" data-order="1">Div2</div>
<div class="sortableDiv" data-order="2">Div3</div>
    <div class="child3 detail">Child3</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g5p2gdy5/1/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a list of 5 items, but you are only sorting 3 of them.

Why not actually nest the child divs inside the parent divs?

```js
$('.sortableDiv').sort(sort_1).appendTo('#sortableContainer');

function sort_1(a, b) { 
  return ($(b).data('order')) < ($(a).data('order')) ? 1 : -1;  

}
```

```css
 .sortableDiv{
   background: #EEE;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   padding:3px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
 }

.detail{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortableContainer">
  <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="3">Div1
    <div class="child1 detail">Child1</div>
  </div>    
  <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="1">Div2</div>
  <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="2">
    Div3
    <div class="child3 detail">Child3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5p2gdy5/3/

---

## EDIT

Since nesting is not possible, let's try also sorting the child divs along with the parent divs.  The parent gets a whole number order like `data-order="1"` and a child gets a decimal number order like `data-order="1.1"` and `data-order="1.2"`

```js
$('.sortableDiv').sort(sort_1).appendTo('#sortableContainer');

function sort_1(a, b) { 
  return ($(b).data('order')) < ($(a).data('order')) ? 1 : -1;  

}
```

```css
.sortableDiv:before{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    padding-right: 2px;
    content: attr(data-order)
}

.detail{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortableContainer">
    <div class="sortableDiv child1 detail" data-order="3.2">Child 1.2</div>
    <div class="sortableDiv child1 detail" data-order="3.1">Child 1.1</div>
    <div class="sortableDiv child3 detail" data-order="2.1">Child3</div>
    
    <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="3">Div1</div>
    <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="1">Div2</div>
    <div class="sortableDiv" data-order="2">Div3</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5p2gdy5/4/

Comment: I can't nest the child div for markup reasons! I thought of only sorting the sortableDiv class. In the process check for next().hasclass("detail") and then put it next to the new order place of the sortable div.

Comment: Well the issue is that you have 5 elements, you remove 3 of them, sort them, and then add them back to the end of the list with `appendTo`.  I've edited my answer to include another solution where you specify an order for every element, not just the parent elements.